# Inserting a Page Break Wherever in ODT Document when Exporting from Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt, page

Is there a simple one-liner to insert a page break wherever when generating ODT from Org mode? I'd rather not dig into styles if I can avoid it. I'd like to be able to do  something like `#+ODT_PAGEBREAK` if there was such a tag, but there isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Three is plenty of examples in [The Authoritative fork of Org mode's ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt?tab=readme-ov-file#the-authoritative-fork-of-org-modes-odt-exporter) and I also anticiapated this question and more or less gave the answer in other question.

Comment: ... the "other question" being https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80822/hiding-headings-in-doc-exported-from-org-mode-to-odt

Comment: @mxnt

>> more or less gave the answer in other question. 
I'm sorry. I don't see any reference to forcing a page break in the "other question." Could you clue me in, please? I'd be much obliged.

Comment: In the docs, I can only find how to generate a page break before or after some specific element (e.g. toc.) I need to generate  a page break wherever/whenever. Is there a one-liner I can use?

Comment: Let me reword my question in Yes/No form:
Is there a one-liner that forces a page break whenever/wherever in exported ODT or PDF document?
It is easier to say yes or no, than to berate me for failing to have found an answer myself.